# JSON datetime to SQL Server database via WCF

Tags: c#, sql, json, wcf

I have noticed a problem over the past couple of days where my dates submitted to an sql server database are wrong. I have a webpage, where users can book facilities. This webpage takes a name, a date, a start time and an end time(BookingID is required for transactions but generated by database), which I format as a JSON string as follows:

```
{"BookingEnd":"\/Date(2012-26-03 09:00:00.000)\/","BookingID":1,"BookingName":"client test 1","BookingStart":"\/Date(2012-26-03 10:00:00.000)\/","RoomID":4}
```

This is then passed to a WCF service, which handles the database insert as follows:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "createbooking")]
    void CreateBooking(Booking booking);

[DataContract]
public class Booking
{
    [DataMember]
    public int BookingID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string BookingName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime BookingStart { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime BookingEnd { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int RoomID { get; set; }

}
```

Booking.svc

```
public void CreateBooking(Booking booking)
    {
        BookingEntity bookingEntity = new BookingEntity()
                                        {
                                            BookingName = booking.BookingName,
                                            BookingStart = booking.BookingStart,
                                            BookingEnd = booking.BookingEnd,
                                            RoomID = booking.RoomID
                                        };
        BookingsModel model = new BookingsModel();
        model.CreateBooking(bookingEntity);

    }
```

Booking Model:

```
public void CreateBooking(BookingEntity booking)
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=cpm;Initial Catalog=BookingDB;Integrated Security=True"))
        using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.CommandText =
                @"IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM Bookings WHERE BookingStart = @BookingStart AND BookingEnd = @BookingEnd AND RoomID= @RoomID )
                    INSERT INTO Bookings ( BookingName, BookingStart, BookingEnd, RoomID ) VALUES ( @BookingName, @BookingStart, @BookingEnd, @RoomID )";

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BookingName", booking.BookingName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BookingStart", booking.BookingStart);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BookingEnd", booking.BookingEnd);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RoomID", booking.RoomID);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            conn.Close();

        }
    }
```

This updates the database but the time ends up "1970-01-01 00:00:02.013" each time I submit the date in the above json format. However, when I do a query in SQL server management studio with the above date format ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.mmm"), it inserts the correct values. Also, if I submit a millisecond datetime to the wcf, the correct date is being inserted. The problem seems to be with the format I am submitting. I am a little lost with this problem. I don't really see why it is doing this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what are the values of your booking.BookingEnd & booking.BookingStart variables ?

Comment: @Dmitriy Reznik, booking.BookingStart, and booking.BookingEnd should be the BookingStart and BookingEnd values of the json string.

Comment: You should have a look at DateTime.ParseExact. With that you can parse the given string to a proper DateTime.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose, you don't use a Json parser while you form your json string. If you use one, you will see that the DateTime class in not serialized to this form `2012-26-03 09:00:00.000`

It should be something like

```
{"BookingEnd":"\/Date(1332683123765+0300)\/"}
```

or

```
{"BookingEnd":"\/Date(1332683194843)\/"}
```

*# of milliseconds since epoch(1970,1,1)*

---

```
public class TestClass
{
    public DateTime BookingEnd;
}

//Using Json.Net
var str1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new TestClass() { BookingEnd = DateTime.Now });

//Using JavaScriptSerializer 
JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var str2 = ser.Serialize(new TestClass() { BookingEnd = DateTime.Now });

//Using DataContractJsonSerializer 
MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream();
DataContractJsonSerializer ser2 = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(TestClass));
ser2.WriteObject(m, new TestClass() { BookingEnd = DateTime.Now });
string str3 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(m.ToArray());
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll try this and see how I get on! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a .NET client to perform the POST then use the below method to POST your request body to a RESTful service:

```
private static byte[] ToByteArrayUsingJsonContractSer<T> (T requestBody)
        {
            byte[] bytes = null;
            var serializer1 = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
            var ms1 = new MemoryStream();
            serializer1.WriteObject(ms1, requestBody);
            ms1.Position = 0;
            var reader = new StreamReader(ms1);
            bytes = ms1.ToArray();
            return bytes;
        }
```

Once you have the bytes of request body then just post it to the stream of the request and monitor it using Fiddler and you should see your JSON request. Make sure to set your Content-Type to `application/json`

Please find a sample request that i have used using the above method with start date as DateTime.Now and booking end date as DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)

```
POST http://localhost/SampleService/Service1.svc/postmethod/new HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Host: rajeshwin7
Content-Length: 144
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

{"BookingEnd":"\/Date(1332842057631+0100)\/","BookingID":1,"BookingName":"client sent","BookingStart":"\/Date(1332755657631+0100)\/","RoomID":2}
```

And once i do the above i get back response as shown below:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 334
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX; path=/; HttpOnly
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 26 Mar 2012 09:54:53 GMT

<Booking xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/XMLService" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><BookingEnd>2012-03-27T10:54:17.631+01:00</BookingEnd><BookingID>1</BookingID><BookingName>client sent from server</BookingName><BookingStart>2012-03-26T10:54:17.631+01:00</BookingStart><RoomID>2</RoomID></Booking>
```

Notice the bookingName element that has a string appended from server (which i have used for testing purpose)

Answer (score -1):

Can you check your JSON format. It should be yyyy-MM-dd. You have yyyy-dd-MM

```
"\/Date(2012-03-26 09:00:00.000)\/"
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I changed it and it still is the same. I can run the value in a query but not in the json string.